# Mapping in R with Web Scraped Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm trying to visualize on a world map a table from the Polity IV series dataset scraped from Wikipedia.

After taking out some variables, I'm looking to visualize countries and their regime types (coded as Polity datasets IV category) by color coding. There is an world map visualization on the webpage as my basis for replication.

I've consulted documentation from this [website](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html) and it appears that I would need to combine my dataset with packaged geographical data. Although, I'm not sure how to do that.

Input:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

polity <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polity_data_series")

table <- polity %>% html_table(fill=T)

second_table <- table[[2]]
second_table <- second_table[c(1,5)]

polity <- second_table

library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(ggplot2)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data = world) +
    geom_sf() +
    xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
    ggtitle("World map", subtitle = paste0("(", length(unique(world$NAME)), " countries)"))
```

Comment: From where is `world` data coming from?

Comment: It's from the syntax within the documentation (a sample world map)

Comment: I loaded the 3 libraries that you have shown and when I run `ggplot` code I get  `Error in ggplot(data = world) : object 'world' not found`

Comment: i forgot to mention that i loaded these previously: install.packages(c("cowplot", "googleway", "ggplot2", "ggrepel", 
"ggspatial", "libwgeom", "sf", "rnaturalearth", "rnaturalearthdata")

Comment: Sorry still cannot find `world` it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```
world2 <- left_join(world, polity,
                    by = c("name" = "Country"))

ggplot(data = world2) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = `Polity datasets IV category`)) +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help. This is what I'm looking for. Although, I'm get this error message while knitting "Error in left_join(world2, polity, by = c(name = "Country")) : 
  object 'world2' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> left_join
Execution halted"

Comment: I think the name of the first object inside the `left_join` function should be `world` rather than `world2`.

Comment: I still get the error after renaming it. Also, the error begins on the line of the beginning of the code chunk, so it's definitely not the naming of the variable.

Comment: Hmm, you may want to run the code line by line, rather than knit in code chunks, in order to pinpoint what's triggering the error messages.

Comment: I figured out a solution by adding a line that specified the use of country data! This made it work. Thank you again for your help!